# several alarmManagerService errors in LogCat (almost 4 per second)

Tags: android, logcat

I'm developing an app on a Samsung galaxy mini 2, and I'm worried about the logcat that is showing lots of errors from the alarmManagerService, almost 4 errors per second...When rebooted the phone, nothing changes....here a little part of my logCat:

```
08-17 12:30:27.189: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 65.163000000**
08-17 12:30:27.189: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:27.189: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:27.589: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 65.563000000
08-17 12:30:27.589: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:27.589: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:27.979: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 65.963000000
08-17 12:30:27.979: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:27.979: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:28.389: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 66.363000000
08-17 12:30:28.389: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:28.389: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:28.789: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 66.763000000
08-17 12:30:28.789: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:28.789: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:29.189: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 67.163000000
08-17 12:30:29.189: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:29.189: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:29.589: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 67.563000000
08-17 12:30:29.589: D/PowerManagerService(194): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:29.589: D/PowerManagerService(194): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
08-17 12:30:29.989: E/AlarmManagerService(194): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 67.963000000
```

I don't really know even if it's a problem or it's all normal, but i'm concerned about battery usage or performances...it seems like android do not stop to work even when the phone is in sleep mode....someone else got similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not related to your app. If you do a search on `android_server_AlarmManagerService_set`, you will see that various Samsung devices do this.

As a test, uninstall your app and reboot. If you still get the `android_server_AlarmManagerService_set` messages, it is guaranteed to not be related to your app.

Comment: You right! after some disinstallation I found the app responsable for this...it's [App Block](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock)! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as my observations go, this is a bug in Android 2.3.6
I happened to check the logs and find the same error messages when my default Alarm failed to ring. After doing a factory reset and hard reset, the system provided alarm seems to work for a few weeks / months. After that, the bug slowly unveils itself.

I set the alarm to 6.30 AM and it doesn't work, say 3 days in a week!
And while inspecting the catlog, it is evident that something is wrong somewhere regarding the whole alarm logic.